# _id vs. _Id in mongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, duplicates, mongodb-query

In this [MSDN sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Getting-started-with-37dbd5bd#content), when I ran it the 2nd time w/ different values for "author" and "title"

```
using (mongo.RequestStart(db)) 
{ 
    var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("books"); 

    BsonDocument = new BsonDocument() 
        .Add("_id", BsonValue.Create(BsonType.ObjectId)) 
        .Add("author", "Ernest Hemingway") 
        .Add("title", "For Whom The Bell Tolls"); 

        collection.Insert(book); 
}
```

I got this error:
Additional information: WriteConcern detected an error ''. (Response was { "err" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: test.test.$*id*  dup key: { : 7 }", "code" : 11000, "n" : 0, "connectionId" : 4, "ok" : 1.0 }).

Basically, "_id" is getting value **7** again. I thought BsonValue.Create(BsonType.ObjectId) is supposed to create a unique 24 character hex string.

Answer (score 2):

Two different things here. To create an new ObjectId then use:

```
 var id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
```

What you have is the constant value for the enumeration of the ["BSON Type"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/), which for an "ObjectId" that constant number is 7.

So ["create" an ObjectId](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#objectid-and-bsonobjectid). All you are doing right now is calling the constant value for the type.